# python minidom xml parsing

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm trying to find a way to get the index number when parsing a xml file with minidom.
xml will look something like this

```
<stuff>
    <morestuff>
        <sometag>catagory1</sometag>
        <path pathversion="1">/path Im looking to for</path> #<--info i'm after
        <path pathversion="2">/path I don't need</path>
        <path pathversion="3">/path I don't need</path>
    </morestuff>
    <morestuff>
        <sometag>catagory2</sometag>
        <path pathversion="1">/other path I'm looking for</path> #<--info i'm after
        <path pathversion="2">/path I don't need</path>
        <path pathversion="3">/path I don't need</path>
    </morestuff>
</stuff>
```

I want to do something like this

```
for element in node.getElementsByTagName('sometag'):
    if element.firstChild.data == 'catagory1':
        elementid = element.indexnumber #<----how do I write the [0], or [1] to a variable so I can use it to discribe the position in the next line
        var1 = node.getElementsByTagName('path')[elementid].firstChild.data
    if element.firstChild.data == 'catagory2':
        elementid = element.indexnumber
        var2 = node.getElementsByTagName('path')[elementid].firstChild.data
```

Comment: I would suggest using elementtree or lxml instead of minidom. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom

Comment: It's not clear what index you're trying to get. Can you give a sample of the desired output? You want the index of `<morestuff>` element among its siblings?

Comment: I'm trying to get the <path pathversion="1"> for both items under <sometag> catigory 1 and catigory 2. The tricky part thats getting me is I need to know which category they came from and the categorys might not be in that order.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the suggestion of elementtree looks like I can grab the index using it as found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763048/elementtree-element-index-look-up I'll see if I can rework this with elementtree.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a dictionary containing the information you wanted:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(test)

paths = {}

for element in doc.getElementsByTagName('morestuff'):
    # get the text value of the sometag tag
    category = element.getElementsByTagName('sometag')[0].firstChild.nodeValue

    # get all the paths which are children of the morestuff element
    for path in element.getElementsByTagName('path'):
        if path.getAttribute('pathversion') == '1':
            pathstr = path.firstChild.nodeValue
            paths[category] = pathstr

print paths
```

The output I get is:

```
{u'catagory1': u'/path Im looking to for', u'catagory2': u"/other path I'm looking for"}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using etree as Keith suggests :-

```
['/path Im looking to for', "/other path I'm looking for"]
```

using this code :-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring('''<stuff>
    <morestuff>
        <sometag>catagory1</sometag>
        <path pathversion="1">/path Im looking to for</path>
        <path pathversion="2">/path I don't need</path>
        <path pathversion="3">/path I don't need</path>
    </morestuff>
    <morestuff>
        <sometag>catagory2</sometag>
        <path pathversion="1">/other path I'm looking for</path>
        <path pathversion="2">/path I don't need</path>
        <path pathversion="3">/path I don't need</path>
    </morestuff>
</stuff>
''')
print [e.text for e in tree.findall('.//morestuff/path[@pathversion="1"]')]
```